# jquery plugin, reference video element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have started jQuery plugin where I want to retrieve the `.duration` and `.currentTime` on a HTML5 video, from within a bound `.on('click', )` event.

I am struggling to capture this information within my `plugin.registerClick` function, here is my code:

```
(function ($) {

$.myPlugin = function (element, options) {

    var defaults = {
            videoOnPage: 0,
            dataSource: 'data/jsonIntervals.txt',
            registerClick: function () { }
    }

    var plugin = this;

    plugin.settings = {}

    var $element = $(element);
         element = element;

    plugin.init = function () {

        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        $element.on('click', plugin.registerClick);

        getJsonIntervals();
    }

    plugin.registerClick = function () {

        var duration = $('video').get(plugin.settings.videoOnPage).duration;

        console.log('duration: ' + duration);
    }

    var startTimes = [];
    var dataSet = false;

    var getJsonIntervals = function () {

        if (dataSet == false) {
                //calls a $.getJSON method.
                //populates startTimes
                //updates dataSet = true;
        };
    }

    plugin.init();

}

$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (undefined == $(this).data('myPlugin')) {
            var plugin = new $.myPlugin(this, options);
            $(this).data('myPlugin', plugin);
        }
    })
};

})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $('#button1').myPlugin();
});
```

Here my sample jsFiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p4w040uz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
plugin.registerClick = function () {
  var video = $('video').get(0);            
  console.log('duration: ' + video.duration);
  console.log('currenttime: ' + video.currentTime);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4w040uz/2/

You need to play the video first then click the button.  The browser has to retrieve the meta data first before it can return it.

Additional reference material you can read up:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp

http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Thanks. I realised this about 30 seconds after the post but was leaving work so couldn't correct myself! Thank you for the links.